# pm2 не обновляет код

Tags: node.js, pm2

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема, загрузил бота на сервер
Далее все делал по этой инструкции:
https://timeweb.cloud/tutorials/nodejs/deploj-node-js-prilozheniya
Я так понимаю, что команда "pm2 start app.js --name "приложение" --watch." должна работать без каких либо "дополнений"
Но код не обновляет, и сервер уже перезапускал, и pm2 restart appName прописывал,но ничего
Что я не так делаю?
Я же правильно понимаю: обновил код на гитхабе и сервер оттуда подтягивает автоматически?